# Making responsive navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, navigation

I am having some trouble about turning navigation bar to responsive navigation. My toggle and navigation positioning not working quite well. The example of the site is down below. I am not quite sure what is the missing part?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "gnav") {
          x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
          x.className = "gnav";
      }
  }
    
  </script>
```

```css
#header .gnav {
 position: relative;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
 width: 587px;
 height: 75px;
 overflow: hidden; /**/
}

.gnav a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}

.gnav .icon {
    display: none;
}


#header .gnav h1 {
 float: left;
}
#header .gnav ul {
 float: left;
 width: 351px;
}
#header .gnav li {
 float: left;
}

#ul_menu{
 /*
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    top:100px;
 */
}
#ul_menu li{
 /*
    width:200px;
    float:left;
  */
   position:relative;
}
#ul_menu li a{
 /*
    width:198px;
    background:#EE0088;
    float:none;
    height:30px;
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #FCF;
    color:#FFF;
 */
}
#header .gnav li .sub_list {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 28px;
    left: 0;
 width: 140px;
 padding: 10px 0 0 0;
 background: #1e2d68;
}
#header .gnav li .sub_list li {
 float: none;
 padding: 0 5px 10px 20px;
 background: #1e2d68;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 11px
}
#header .gnav li .sub_list li a {
 color: #fff;
}
#header .gnav li .sub_list.sub01 {
 width: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .gnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .gnav .icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .gnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .gnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .gnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gnav clearfix" id="myTopnav">
     <h1><a href="index.html"><img src="images/index/logo.gif" width="236" height="75" alt="株式会社ジェイウィル J-WILL CORPORATION"></a></h1>
     <ul id="ul_menu" class="clearfix">
      <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/common/gnav01.gif" width="111" height="38" alt="HOME"></a></li>
      <li>
       <a href="company/index.html"><img src="images/common/gnav02.gif" width="100" height="38" alt="企業情報"></a>
       <ul class="sub_list sub01">
        <li><a href="company/index.html">代表ご挨拶</a></li>
        <li><a href="company/index.html#sc02">行動指針</a></li>
        <li><a href="company/index.html#sc03">企業概要</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
       <a href="business/index.html"><img src="images/common/gnav03.gif" width="140" height="38" alt="事業内容"></a>
       <ul class="sub_list sub02">
        <li><a href="business/index.html">ジェイウィルの強み</a></li>
        <li><a href="business/index.html#sc03">販売実績</a></li>
        <li><a href="business/index.html#sc06">マンション一棟<br>仲介実績</a></li>
        <li><a href="business/index.html#sc02">マンション用地<br>仲介実績</a></li>
        <li><a href="business/index.html#sc05">戸建用地仲介実績</a></li>
        <li><a href="business/index.html#sc01">事業概要</a></li>
       </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="staff/index.html"><img src="images/common/gnav04.gif" width="111" height="37" alt="社員紹介"></a></li>
      <li><a href="careers/index.html"><img src="images/common/gnav05.gif" width="100" height="37" alt="採用情報"></a></li>
      <li><a href="contact/"><img src="images/common/gnav06.gif" width="140" height="37" alt="お問い合わせ"></a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

the icon is not toggling and I make the screen smaller navbar is not disappearing. the problem is media or is it something about main css? I really appreciate if any one can figure the problem is out! 
Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Bootstrap 4 for creating a responsive navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/).  You can have it done in minutes.

Comment: unfortunately I already made a navbar, I dont want to make it again. just want to make it properly responsive. but thanks for advice.

Comment: I completely understand that.  In that case, maybe comparing yours to theirs may help?